# How to replace FQN in PHPDoc with short name (with use)?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

How can I automatically replace FQN in all files?

Before:

```
/**
 * @param \app\models\Test $test
 */
```

After:

```
use app\models\Test;

/**
 * @param Test $test
 */
```

Comment: Automatically in all files? Run "Code | Inspect Code..." and use fixes there (if it's available for all files). Inside the actual file -- use Quick Fix  menu (`Alt+Enter` on the issue or via Light Bulb icon) and choose appropriate action.

Comment: @LazyOne My code inspection doesn’t show FQN, maybe some settings are needed?

Comment: Such Inspection is ON by default. Should be this one: https://postimg.cc/7JLvM10j

Comment: @LazyOne this works for code, not for phpdocs

Comment: Works for me. Same inspection 1) https://postimg.cc/XBdtcVvB 2) https://postimg.cc/V5tycFFs

Comment: @LazyOne Not working for me) 1) http://prntscr.com/ovkmv4 2) http://prntscr.com/ovkn3v

Comment: So .. you **already have** `use` statement for that class (`Request` is already imported, based on function parameters). **In such case it's a different inspection** (so it's not what your initial description shows): 1) https://postimg.cc/RNkdY3M8 2) https://postimg.cc/mcXF0qYD 3) https://postimg.cc/t7dMWNpT -- on your 2nd screenshot it is disabled 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not imported that class yet (no `use` statements for that class) then it's controlled by `PHP | Code Style | Fully qualified name usage` inspection.

[image]

If it's already imported but you still have FQN references and want to simplify them then it's `PHP | Code Style | Fully qualified name usage` inspection.

[image]

---

You can run `Code | Inspect Code...` and apply offered fixes from there: they could be offered for 1 place only as well as for the whole thing at once (fix will be applied to the whole file or all selected files) -- not every inspection offers "batched" fix.

[image]

---

When doing it manually via <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> menu (or light bulb if using mouse).

Not yet imported class case:

[image]

Already imported class case:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked after the update from 2018.1.2 to 2019.2